# How to remove zeros from a cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell called `sequences (406 x 1)` where each cell is `(1x25 double)`.

```
sequences=randi(5,406,25); #create an array with values max 5, 406x25
sequences(50:65,5)=0; #Add zeros
sequences=num2cell(sequences,2); #convert to cell
```

I would like to remove any zeros from any cell, keeping the structure the same (just removing the individual zeros). I've tried every answer from stack and mathworks, but nothing will shift them.

e.g. 1

```
idxZeros = cellfun(@(c)(isequal(c,0)), sequences);
sequences(idxZeros) = [];
```

Doesn't change anything about the cell at all.

e.g. 2

```
zero_idx = bsxfun(@eq, [sequences{:}], 0);
sequences(zero_idx) = {[]};
```

e.g.3

```
 sequences([sequences{:}]==0)={[]};
```

deletes a load of cells

**Note**: I don't mind leaving it as an array, deleting zeros and reshaping, but I do need a cell at the end of it.
Any thoughts would be much appreciated

Comment: _remove the zeros that appear in the individual cells_ Does that mean (1) removing any zero from any cell? (2) Setting to `[]` any cell that only has zeros? (3) Deleting cells that only have zeros?

Comment: Remove any zero from any cell please, leaving the overall structure the same (ie. rows of numbers with no zeros).

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify that, so that it can be useful for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes any zero from any cell, leaving the results in each cell as a row vector:

```
result = cellfun(@(x) nonzeros(x).', sequences, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Or you can replace `nonzeros` by logical indexing:

```
result = cellfun(@(x) x(x~=0), sequences, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Luis Mendo, it's spot on. This was the only answer on stack that I didn't try because I couldn't get my head around the 'UniformOutput' bit. What's so particular about my cell that the other answers don't work?

Comment: @HCAI Approach 1 doesn't work because you are comparing each cell (which is a 1x25 array) with 0 (which is a 1x1 array). So they are never equal. In approaches 2 and 3 you concatenate into a numeric vector and lose the cell structure.